# How to open and close div with single button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am creating a chat popup button. I want to open and close popup/div with a single button.

```
<div class="menu-chat">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="float" id="menu-open">
    <img src="<?php echo plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'buttons/chat.svg'; ?>">
    </a>        

<div id="menu-popup">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="mailto:hello@covers.pk" id="menu-email">
        <img src="<?php echo plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'buttons/email.svg'; ?>">
        </a></li>   
        <li><a href="tel:+923038518000" id="menu-call">
        <img src="<?php echo plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'buttons/call.svg'; ?>">
        </a></li>   
        <li><a href="https://m.me/Printed.Mobile.Covers" id="menu-facebook">
        <img src="<?php echo plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'buttons/facebook.svg'; ?>">
        </a></li>
        <li><a href="https://wa.me/9203038518000" id="menu-whatsapp">
        <img src="<?php echo plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'buttons/whatsapp.svg'; ?>">
        </a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want the popup to appear when the button is clicked. When the button is clicked again I want it to disappear.

Comment: on click just toggle class like active.

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way to do this is by using JQuery `toggle()` method. When used with no parameters, the `toggle()` method simply toggles the visibility of elements:

```
$(function() {

  $("#menu-open").on("click", function() {
    $("#menu-popup").toggle();
  });

});
```